# Automatic void * to C++ class cast

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to bind some C++ classes to Lua. When using single inheritance the problem is very easy, however when using multiple inheritance, there is a problem to determine the type of class that a void * holds.

Lua can only manage user's data via void pointers, so when you have the following:

```
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A() { }
    ~A() { }
};

class B {
private:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_count;

public:
    B() { }
    ~B() { }
};

class C
    : public A
    , public B
{
private:
    std::string m_title;

public:
    C() { }
    ~C() { }
};
```

Declaring a pointer to C and cast it to B will auto align the pointer to the placement of B in the class C, as the following explain:

```
int main()
{
        C *c = new C();
        B *b = c;

        printf("c = %p, b = %p\n", c, b);

        return 0;
}
```

And the output:

$ ./a.out
c = 0x801807040, b = 0x801807050

So here, we see that the B class is located after the size of A plus some internal data that the compiler adds.

Now the question is, how to automatically cast the void * pointer that holds the class to the desired type using templates? The only thing we now about the void pointer is that it also holds a string with the class name, so for A, we have "A", thus we can create a kind of map to be used.

For instance, I would like to be able to do something like

```
B *b = castFromVoid<B>(myVoidPtr);
```

And because I know that the myVoidPtr has its class string set to "C" or to "B", I'm sure that it can be casted to B, but I just need to have a function that actually do the cast for me and I don't find any solution for that using templates.

Comment: How do you plan to access your data structures in Lua?

Comment: Some methods are provided to the class type, that's why we have the class name as string. For instance, if you provide a class C to Lua, a special __index function is provided so it looks for parent class if the method is not found. Thus if you want to access a method from class A it works because A is aligned directly at the beginning of the C class bytes so the cast from void * is correct, unfortunately for B it won't so the pointer will points at incorrect location.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you want ?

```
template<typename T>
T *castFromVoid(void *ptr) {
    return dynamic_cast<T *>(static_cast<A *>(ptr));
}
```

However, you need RTTI to be enabled in your compiler, and have at least one virtual method in your classes (destructor is a good candidate, isn't it ?).

This assumes all of your classes will inherit from a same base class (here A), because RTTI cannot be performed on a pointer to void.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally done something with a map using a from-to basis. As we know the type by string I do something like this:

```
typedef std::function<void * (void *)> Converter;

map<string, map<string, Converter>> converters;

template <class From, class To>
void createConverter(string fromName, string toName)
{
        converters[toName][fromName] = [&] (void *ptr) -> void * {
                From *from = static_cast<From *>(ptr);

                return static_cast<To *>(from);
        };
}

template <class To>
To * getPointer(string fromName, string toName, void *ptr)
{
        return static_cast<To *>(converters[toName][fromName](ptr));
}

int main()
{
        createConverter<C, A>("C", "A");
        createConverter<C, B>("C", "B");

        C *c = new C();
        B *b = getPointer<B>("C", "B", c);

        // Use b here..

        return 0;
}
```

The only drawback, is that you need to call createConverter for each possibility, but I think I will create a function that automatically create them for each parents and parents of these parents.